# Android line loading animation

Tags: android, animation, loading, android-progressbar

How can I make an animation in Android like this one or similar?

I don't know where to start, how to make the lines and how to make them move.

See the progress bar displayed on this site: http://tinyurl.com/oqy8zef

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an indeterminate progress bar

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true" />
```

But you should not include "Loading..." text according to [guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html)

Comment: good enough, always used the circle one, forgot about this one

Comment: I was just about to answer exactly that xD :(